# Visual Studio - Step over disables itself

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm having some weird quirks that are stopping me from debugging properly and I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced similar? I've tried resetting all my VS keyboard mappings to the default but that hasn't solved my issue.

Basically I debug through some lines F10, F10, F10, F10 and this works normally.

Then at some point normally after 3/4 lines F10 stops working, and the command on the toolbar disables itself. You can see this in the screenshot just above the ProductConnector.cs tab currently selected.

[image: ugh]

F11 will work at this point, but F10 does not. Changing focus to another window will fix it for about 3/4 presses of F10 again at which point it will break.

Has anyone else experienced this/have any suggestions on how to fix? It is infuriating.

**EDIT**

I should add I'm on VS2012 Pro SP4. I'll resort to logging a bug with Visual Studio next but imagine the turnaround on that will be quote slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As none of my colleagues were experiencing this I decided to go through my extensions - seems that the issue is due to the .NET Reflector extension installed. Disabling it fixes the problem.... Off to log an issue with Reflector.

Here's my post on the Reflector forum for anyone else who has this issue: http://forums.reflector.net/questions/4748/reflector-extensions-breaks-f10-functionality.html

Comment: Thank you very much! This is definitely the problem caused by Reflector. Btw. the debugging is quicker also

Comment: This was fixed in a release last week (8.3.3.115), available from http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/95789cdb-08f9-4dae-9b2f-fc45a452ad77.

Comment: This has not been fixed, even in the current version (9.0.1.374) on VS 2015. It was driving me bonkers thinking VS was broken, but luckily I found someone mentioning that this extension causes the issues. Since disabling the extension debugging has also become much faster - I recommend disabling this extension generally and only activating it when you really need .NET Reflector functionality from within VS.