# Can't step over code in Visual studio while debugging

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2013

I've been experiencing an issue with stepping through my code in Visual Studio 2013.

These seems like a fairly serious issue so I'd be surprised if no one has noticed anything like this. As you can see in the screenshot below I, while paused in the debugger both Step Into and Step Over are disabled. However this issue also seems to be temporal as they do come back after about 10 or 20 seconds. It's probably also worth mentioning sometimes it's just Step Over, sometimes just Step Into and sometimes both.

[image: Debug menu]

I have a feeling this might be due to a plugin. The main plugins I have installed at the moment are  `ReSharper 8.1`, `Reflector` and `Web Essentials`.

I've tried searching around but can't seem to find anything. Is this a know issue anywhere?

Comment: I had a similar issue with the .NET Reflector Visual Studio extension used in VS2012.

Comment: Have you tried removing or disabling Resharper to see if your issue persists?

Comment: @faceman I do have Reflector installed.. I'll try disabling some plugins.

Comment: @Daniel Have you seen this SO post: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21138136/1108036)

Comment: @faceman No I haven't, looks very familiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the issue was the `Reflector Pro 8.3.2.99` plugin as @faceman suggested. Disabling the plugin corrects the issue.

It looks like there may be a fix: 
http://forums.reflector.net/questions/4748/reflector-extensions-breaks-f10-functionality.html